# How to uniquely identify each Task in javafx?

Tags: java, javafx, concurrency, task

I have a ListView containing URLs. When a user click on one of the URL, a video is downloaded. I am calling the video download function within a Task which in turn is called in a Thread. A user can click on multiple video URL and the video would start to download. A separate Task would be created for each of the video. What i want to know is how to uniquely identify Task for each video?

Function to download video:

```
public void videoFileDownload(){
            try {

                videoDownloadUrl =  lblURL.getText().toString();

                IndexOfThisNode = hbox.getId();


                String path = "XXXX";
                downloadThisVideo = new VGet(new URL(videoDownloadUrl),new File(path));             




                downloadThisVideo.download();   
                System.out.println("Download this video: " + videoDownloadUrl + downloadThisVideo.getVideo().getState());

                System.out.println("Download complete");



            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("Retrying...");
            }  
        }
```

Function containing Task:

```
    public void showDetailsButton(){

        btnSMDetails.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, (e)->{
        System.out.println("\n" + "The index is: " + getIndex() + "\n");
        showLoader();


         //Task created to download videos in background without blocking UI
         Task downloadVideoTask = new Task<Void>() {
            @Override
            public Void call() {
               //SIMULATE A FILE DOWNLOAD
                videoFileDownload();
               try {
                   Thread.sleep(1000);
               } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                     e.printStackTrace();
               }
              return null;
            }
         };

         new Thread(downloadVideoTask).start();

        downloadVideoTask.setOnSucceeded(taskFinishEvent ->{showLoader(); /*isButtonClicked="0";*/});
  });
}
```

Comment: The question seems a bit too broad - what do you mean by identifying the task? Presumably, each `Task` must have the URL of the video it downloads - that alone may be enough. Another way is to assign an ID upon creation, or simply using reference equality.  What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @sillyfly  While the video is being downloaded, the listcell is disabled and progress bar is shown. However when i scroll all the way down and then back to that cell, it is no longer disabled and progress bar is not shown. So, i want to tell the listcell not to update the cell in which the download button is pressed. A friend told me this can be achieved using Task and storing the task

Comment: Create a [MCVE] that demonstrates the actual problem you are trying to solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Listcells don't exist in a one to one relationship with the underlying list. There's only enough listcells instantiated to fill the viewport of the listview plus a couple extra. Data is swapped in and out of the listcells through the updateCell method.

So you can't store data in a listcell, since the cell will get reused for another list item if you scroll the list.

What you need to do is to store a reference to the task in the underlying list item. Modify your updateCell method to bind the visibility and value of your progress bar in the listcell to the task progress property.